# Determining E-mail character sets

Tags: email, unicode, asp-classic, pop3

My boss assigned me a task of displaying all international characters correctly on our e-mail server that runs on our frontend website. The website uses asp-classic.

I looked at our mail_body.asp code to see how the server was handling the text files received from POP3 and this is what I found:

```
Set bobj = Server.CreateObject("Basp21")
If InStr(UCase(filecontent),"?UTF-8?") > 0 or InStr(UCase(filecontent),"CHARSET=""UTF-8""" ) > 0 Then
    bobj.CodePage = 65001
ElseIf  InStr(UCase(filecontent),"EUC-KR") or InStr(UCase(filecontent),"KS_C_5601-1987") > 0 or InStr(UCase(filecontent),"CONTENT-TRANSFER-ENCODING: BASE64") > 0 Then
    bobj.CodePage = 949
    'response.Write "euc-kr"
    'response.Write "UTF-8"
ElseIf InStr(UCase(filecontent),"CHARSET=JOHAB") > 0 Then
    bobj.CodePage = 1361
    'response.Write "JOHAB"
ElseIf InStr(UCase(filecontent),"CHARSET=X-MAC-KOREAN") > 0 Then
    bobj.CodePage = 10003   
    'response.Write "X-MAC-KOREAN"
ElseIf InStr(UCase(filecontent),"CHARSET=X-EBCDIC-KOREANEXTENDED") > 0 Then
    bobj.CodePage = 20833   
    'response.Write "X-EBCDIC-KOREAN"
ElseIf InStr(UCase(filecontent),"CHARSET=ISO-2022-KR") > 0 Then
    bobj.CodePage = 50225
    'response.Write "ISO-2022-KR"   
ElseIf InStr(UCase(filecontent),"CHARSET=""GB2312""") > 0 or InStr(UCase(filecontent),"CHARSET=GB2312") Then
    bobj.CodePage = 936
Else
    bobj.CodePage = 65001
End If

...
outarray=bobj.ReadMail(contents,"subject:to:from:date:X-OriginalArrivalTime:",dirname)
```

I think it's safe to say that above code is not elegant at all, but it gets the job done for the most part. It's a Korean website, so the code is looking for headers that are non-unicode but is written in Korean. Otherwise, it assumes that the e-mail received is UTF-8.

So whenever there are mails with character set other than UTF-8 and any of the defined Korean code pages in the code, the parsed text gets all jumbled up.

Because my boss have asked me to "make the e-mail content display all international characters", the only solution I can think of is to [exhaustively check for all character sets listed here which the header can contain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and set the code page appropriately but this doesn't seem to be a good solution.

I'm wondering what the practical approach would be here to take. Many email services like hotmail and gmail have no problem displaying international characters so I'd like to know how they approached this kind of problem, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The practical approach is to parse out the value of `charset=*` and convert the content to some unified internal encoding. Pseudocode (since I'm not an ASP person at all):

```
charset  = parseMailHeaders(mail.headers, 'charset')  // e.g. 'ISO-2022-KR'
mailBody = convertEncoding(charset, 'UTF-16', mail.body)
```

The hypothetical `parseMailHeaders` extracts the value of `charset=*` from the appropriate mail header. Depending on what values your hypothetical `convertEncoding` function accepts you may need to do some normalization on the extracted `charset` value, but that's basically it. From then on you know the content is UTF-16 encoded and can treat it as such.

Comment: This seems like the logical thing to do. Conversion is pretty straight forward once I know exactly which character set I am working with (I'm pretty sure there was a built in functionality for this in ASP to easily convert the encoding) however, finding out which character set the email is composed in still requires me to exhaustively check for all possible character sets embedded in my mailheader inside the hypothetical parseMailHeaders function. The latter process was exactly what I wanted to avoid. I'm wondering if you can shed some light on this matter. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "exhaustively check". You'd extract the value of the charset from the mail headers and check if your encoding library supports this charset. You only need to exhaustively cross-reference individual values if the value in the email header and the internal name for the encoding differ. I admit I don't know the ASP API for this, but can you not simply throw an encoding name as string at a function and it will tell you whether it supports this encoding or not?

Comment: My shallow understanding of ASP tells me no, that is not possible because there isn't an equivalent of "tryEncodingConvert" in ASP API, so it's either the charset supplied as a string in the convert function works or the whole page fails. although I might be wrong, I'd like to get a confirmation on this by someone who knows.